# Install SSL Certificate for Tomcat 8 on New Server

Tags: ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I downloaded the following files from my provider:

[image]

Can I install the SSL certificate on a new (Ubuntu) server? If so, how? Or do I need to create a new private key and CSR and request a new certificate?

Comment: CSR is needed to issue an SSL certificate, and when generating a CSR you will get a private key, you need this private key to install the issued SSL certificate.

Comment: Although ServerFault is the most appropriate place for your question, this has been covered several times on StackOverflow (e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49386683/11748454)).